# Symfony2 security firewall redirect

Tags: security, symfony, redirect, firewall

In my firewall in the file "security.yml", I want to do a redirect action when the users is not login. **But this redirection don't go to a login form**. I want redirect the anonimous users to the home page (or a 403 page with link to home page).

anonimous_users --go--> secured_page --redirect--> home_page

But I don't know if it's possible and if yes, how can I do write this in the security.yml.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your code, this is the basic workflow: You need some kind of access control.. areas users need specific roles to access:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/secret/, roles: ROLE_LOGGED_IN_USER }
```

You can adjust that to your needs. So far accessing the url /secret/ will lead the user to the login page you provided under the form login. Note that a firewall does not mean that the user will explicitely be redirected. A firewall is just an area on your page that is under some kind of - let's say - supervision. Blocking content for roles happens over `access_control`.

Read on here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have saw this method. But it don't feet, because I have two login protocole. Login form and CAS. So if I use access_controle, the security redirect the anonimous users to login form page, and it's not good if it's a CAS user.

I have find a solution I have write 3 secured area. One for login_form, one for CAS, and the last is my admin page with a false login_form that he redirect to my home page, like this :

`admin_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            context: riac_auth
            form_login:
                login_path:  /home`

with the same context of the 2 others secured area when you are identified in one of them, you are login for the admin area.

For now I have try with 2 login form and it's working. Now I need to work with the BeSimpleSsoBundle.